# Locate element in Bootstrap tour by Class Name, Css or Xpath

Tags: bootstrap-tour

I am using bootstrap tour.

```
@Html.ActionLink("New", "Create", "Test", new { test= Model.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
```

I would like to access the above mentioned item. But I do not have an Id for that. How would I access that elelemt

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what language that code is that you posted, but you can use class names to locate an element. Just do something like:

```
element: 'button.btn.btn-primary'
```

That should work, if it's the only item on the page that matches. If not, you'll need to add an id attribute or use a more specific query.